# In C#, how can you have a global generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

So I have a base set of abstract classes using BaseEngine namespace, and the real game project deriving the set.

There are many base classes that have a set of abstract methods and predefined methods such as:
Item, Entity, Skill

```
public abstract class Item 
{
    public string name;
    public void DestroyItemInBaseEngine () 
    {
        // bunch of codes
    }
    public abstract void BakeItemTheWayYouWant ();
}

public abstract class SkillManager
{
    public abstract T InteractItemWithSkill<T> (T item)
        where T:Item, new(); //not sure if this particular line is valid, but this was written just to help you understand
}
```

And deriving classes such as:

```
public class GameItem : Item
{
    public int variableSpecificToThisGameProject;

    // and other implementation for this specific game...
}
```

Now, Within BaseEngine, it would have abstract classes that refer Item multiple times in managers like BaseItemManager. Each game would manage differently so these managers must be derived as well. When a specific game project derives BaseItemManager, it would have to use GameItem.

BaseEngine was created to be able to be used with different projects, a basically set of abstract classes.

Every time when these derived objects are being referred in the game project, you either have to cast it, or use generic type in abstract methods like such:

```
if (ValidateItemObject<GameItem> (GameItem item) != null)
    // do something with it
```

So because GameItem and other types are decided at compile time, is there anyway to declare something like T = GameItem, S = GameSkill for the entire project so we don't have to mention  every time related methods (like above) or classes are called?

I tried my best to make my case as clear as possible, but let me know if isn't clear what I'm trying to do.

EDIT:

```
protected abstract T ConvertTableToItem<T> (T item, LuaTable luaTable) where T:BaseItem;


protected override ProjectItem SetItemAPI<ProjectItem> (ProjectItem newItem, LuaTable luaTable)
{
    newItem.desc = "test";
}
```

This wouldn't work saying desc is not a member of the class. I can guarantee that it is. desc (public string desc) is defined in ProjectItem.

ProjectItem is a derived class of BaseItem.

Comment: So basically you're tired of having `ValidateItemObject<GameItem> (item)` and would rather want a project-wide alias such as `ValidateGameItem(item)`? Btw I think `if (ValidateItemObject<GameItem> (GameItem item) != null)` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Yep! Like, global-scale type alias, so to speak. The reason is not because I'm just tired, but some BaseEngineManager would have to refer objects like GameItem and manage them. For example, BaseItemManager has a dictionary<string, T> (where T would be GameItem), and BaseSkillManager would try to use something like "BaseItemManager<GameItem >.dictionary.ContainsKey(itemID)", but at the time of writing the base code, since BaseEngine is being designed for future projects as well, we do not know GameItem exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to declare a class with a fixed type parameter for a generic type, the simplest thing is to just inherit the generic type while specifying the type parameter you want. For example:

```
static class SomeSpecificClass : SomeBaseClass<GameItem> { ... }
```

Then any method in `SomeBaseClass<T>` that depends on the type parameter `T` can be called via `SomeSpecificClass` without specifying the type parameter `T`.

That said, the other tool in your toolbox that would probably address at least the example you provided is to take advantage of C#'s type inference for generic methods.

For example, if you have a base-class generic method like this:

```
class SomeBaseClass
{
    public static T ValidateItemObject<T>(T item) where T : Item
    {
        // ...something
    }
}
```

Then you don't actually need to use the type parameter when calling the method, as long as the parameter you pass is correctly typed. For example:

```
GameItem gameItem = ...;

if (SomeBaseClass.ValidateItemObject(gameItem) != null)
{
    // ...something
}
```

(Naturally, if the code is in a class that inherits `SomeBaseClass`, then you don't actually need to specify the class name when calling the method).

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough. I edited and added something from my code. abstract is defined in a base manager, and override method is defined in the derived manager. Could you look at my added code and see why it's not working?

Comment: @MaxHunter: you seem to be trying to declare a generic method with a specific type. But that's not allowed, and in fact C# treats your declaration like any other generic method declaration. It's interpreting `ProjectItem` in that context as the generic type parameter, and without any constraints, the type won't have the member you want. Try `T SetItemAPI<T> (T newItem, LuaTable luaTable) where T : ProjectItem` instead. I can't _guarantee_ that will work, since you still aren't providing a complete code example. But it should at least be closer to what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible.since ProjectItem could be anything in the future projects. I guess it's just not possible with c# on what I'm trying to do...

Comment: @MaxHunter: again, with a _complete_ code example it's likely a solution could be proposed. Until you provide that, it's impossible to state anything with certainty. That said, if `ProjectItem` could literally be anything in the future projects, then you couldn't reasonably expect to write that method anyway, i.e. making the assumption that the type has the `desc` field to assign to.